# Parse.com match all pointers on array in given relation column

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I have `Conversation` classes with a `members` relation attribute pointing to `User` class.

This `members` attribute consists of people belong to a particular conversation.

Now I want to query if given array of pointers `User` is part of particular conversation given that all elements must match.

I tried to use `containsAll("members", users)` but instead got `undefined`.
`containedIn()` worked but it returned all matching conversation that has at least one matching `User` in array.
`equalTo("members", users)` was not working as well and note that the `users` variable is array of pointers and not just array of strings `objectId`, but I also tried that one but got me nowhere.

Here's what I tried:
* Created AND queries where `userRelationQuery.equalTo('member', ParseUser1)` up to N number of users and still didn't work

Here's my solution but feel free to correct this for improvement

```js
const members = getMembers();

let query = new Parse.Query("Conversation").equalTo(
 "members",
 members[0]
);

for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
 query = new Parse.Query("Conversation")
   .matchesKeyInQuery("objectId", "objectId", query)
   .equalTo(
     "members",
     members[i]
   );
}

const chat = await query.includeAll().first();
```

Comment: Hi! Are you still facing this error?

Comment: Yes, I still stick to my solution though...

Comment: Can you please paste here the content of the variable members?

Comment: members is just a relation of _User

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
var conversationClass = Parse.Object.extend('Conversation');
var conversationQuery = new Parse.Query(conversationClass);
return conversationQuery.first()
    .then(queryResult => {
        var userRelationQuery = queryResult.relation('members').query(); //You can get all users releated to this conversation
        //userRelationQuery.equalTo('username', 'Blank0330') // Or you can add more conditions
        return userRelationQuery.find()
            .then(users => {
                return users; //This is your releated users
            });
    });
```

For more information about [Parse-JS-SDK Relation](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#relations)

Comment: See my solution above. I want to check if given N number of users are all members of particular conversation and get it. I tried creating AND queries where `userRelationQuery.equalTo("members", ParseUser{N})` but still didn't work.